# Incorrect data input with fstream

Tags: c++, input, fstream

I tried to read in data from a text file using fstream but got wrong data.

```
ifstream fin ("C:\\Users\\rEgonicS\\Documents\\test.in");
int number;
fin >> number;
cout << number;
```

`test.in` is simply `12`.
`cout` reads `4273190`.
Can someone explain why this is so and how to fix it?

Comment: Is test.in literally "12" with quotations or is it just 12, and how is it encoded? If you aren't sure, what is the file size and what program did you save it with?

Comment: It is simply 12. I saved it in notepad and the file size is 4 bytes and 4KB on disk.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that the file open failed. Check the status after opening, and also after reading; for a simple test, do something like this:

```
ifstream fin ("C:\\Users\\rEgonicS\\Documents\\test.in");
if (!fin) cout << "File open failed\n";
int number;
fin >> number;
if (!fin) cout << "File read failed\n";
cout << number;
```

This might give a further clue as to what's going on.

Comment: I ran the above program and both "File open failed" and "File read failed" came up.

Comment: So that means it failed to open (it will then fail to read since it's not open). Is the path correct? Is the file readable?